# Update debug source in Chrome after document.write()

Tags: javascript, ajax, debugging

I'm making a completely Ajax web app, including login. I use document.write() to rewrite the whole document with what is returned from the Ajax login (including new javascript), but afterward I cannot debug anything because the source still looks like how it looked beforehand when I inspect in Chrome.

Is there a way to update the source for debugging after a document.write(), OR is doing it this way a terrible practice and would be much better if I only rewrote only the html or a portion thereof, and kept all the javascript static through all page alterations?

Comment: doesn't rebuilding the document with `document.write` defeat the purpose of a completely ajax web app?

Comment: @KevinB I suppose you've got me there. I actually already moved on to just replace the body, but I was interested to see if anyone knows how to keep Source in the Chrome debugger updated to changes.